# Divide by Zero warning is not caught in a PHP try/catch block

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I have this PHP code.  Whenever `y` becomes zero, it shows a warning instead of catching the exception.  Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
try
{
    return($x % $y); 
    throw new Exception("Divide error..");
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Exception:".$e->getMessage();
}
```

I got this warning:

```
Warning: Division by zero in file.php
```

The catch block is not run.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not tell us what kind of warning you get?!

Comment: I've fixed your indentation, you might want to check the preview box underneath the question area next time: you can see how your code will come out, and fix it up a bit for easier reading. Remember, the easier you question is to read, the more answers you might get?

Comment: @ThiefMaster:  i have posted the warning check it out.

Comment: @ibu: thanks, i have removed the return statement. Now i am able to catch the exception but it is still showing me warning..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A warning is not an exception. Warnings cannot be caught with exception handling techniques. Your own exception is never thrown since you always `return` before.

You can suppress warnings using the `@` operator like `@($x % $y)`, but what you should really do is make sure `$y` does not become 0.

I.e.:

```
if (!$y) {
    return 0; // or null, or do something else
} else {
    return $x % $y;
}
```

Comment: i have removed the return statement.  Now i am able to catch the exception but it is still showing me warning..

Comment: @Aby If you remove the `return` statement, you'll **always** throw and catch the exception. Exceptions are completely useless here. And regarding the warning, read my answer again.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are executing the `return` before the `throw`. Hence the `throw` is never executed and no exception is thrown nor caught.

Comment: Ok.  I have removed the return statement now.  But it is still showing me warning..

Answer (score -1):

this is how it should be done

```
$value;

try
{
    $value = $x%$y; 
}
catch(Exception $e){
  throw new Exception("Divide error..");
  echo "Exception:".$e->getMessage();
}

return $value
```

But since you are getting a warning if you want to hide the error and handle it discretely
You can use the `@` sign

```
$value = @$x%$y;
```

now you can test the value and see if it has the value it has