# Php try catch not working php 7.0.4

Tags: php, exception

```
try{
//division by zero
$number = 5/0;
}
catch(Exception $ex){
echo 'Got it!';
}

Warning: Division by zero in D:\Sistemim\Server\WebSite\mckportal\test\hatakont.php on line 13
```

What could be the reason?
How can I fix?
He was working with PHP 5.3.
The 7.0.4 version does not work.

Comment: "He was working with PHP 5.3" - [really?](https://3v4l.org/N60N9)  Maybe you had an [error handler](http://docs.php.net/set_error_handler) set up that "converted" the warning into an exception.

Comment: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/0OQLi)

Comment: Have you read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php#118928)?

Comment: The comment on the PHP site linked by @Egg is misleading. And the sample code doesn't work. It defines an error handler but it doesn't install it.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution to the problem.
[Sample: https://3v4l.org/jk7BS](https://3v4l.org/jk7BS)

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if (!!$errstr) {
        throw new Exception($errstr);
    }
    return false;
}

set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');
```

After writing this code, you can control, such as exceptions in Java and other languages.

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if (!!$errstr) {
        throw new Exception($errstr);
    }
    return false;
}

set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');

try{
    //division by zero
    //$number = 5/0;
    unlink("c:\boot.bat");
    $a=5+3;
    echo $a;
}
    catch(Exception $ex){
    echo  "Dotum bi hata yapmış olmalısın mesaj bu:".$ex->getMessage(), ' : Hadi kolay gelsin sana canım'; 
}
```

Comment: Indeed, that's the way to do it. This is also suggested by the PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php#errorexception.examples). PHP 7 changed into exceptions some of the warnings and errors it used to trigger on previous version. Let's hope they will continue this trend and sometime in the future we won't need to write code to convert the errors to exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

First, the code you posted works the same on both PHP 5 and PHP 7. It didn't use to throw an exception on PHP 5; this functionality (throw exceptions instead of triggering runtime errors and warnings) was introduced in PHP 7.

You could in PHP 5 (and you still can in PHP 7) install an error handler that converts the errors to exceptions and throws them. There already are several links (in other answers and comments) to answers where this technique is displayed.

The documentation of the new class [`DivisionByZeroError`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php) (introduced in PHP 7) explains:

> `DivisionByZeroError` is thrown when an attempt is made to divide a number by zero.

Unfortunately, it seems the exception is thrown only on `$x % 0` and `intdiv($x, 0)`. The division by zero using the regular division operator `$x / 0` doesn't throw the exception, it still works the same way it worked on PHP 5 (i.e. triggers a warning).

There is a [bug #71306](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71306) reported for this situation on the PHP support site but it was officially classified as "not a bug" because the division operator `/` produces a floating point number and the floating point representation provides support for `±INF` or `NaN`.

In conclusion, in PHP 7, the division by zero using `/` triggers a warning and returns `INF` or `-INF`. Only the modulo operator (`%`) and the integer division (function [`intdiv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php)) throw [`DivisionByZeroError`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php) when the divider is zero.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Dividing by zero returns a warning and warnings cannot be caught with exception handlers. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6040555/1441858.</strike>

Apologies, I now see that [PHP7 throws an error on division by zero](http://php.net/manual/en/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php).

Comment: The answer you linked to was written 5 years ago. It definitely doesn't cover PHP 7.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. [PHP7 throws an error](http://php.net/manual/en/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php) on division by zero.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not that simple. The documentation is misleading :-( Read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35915946/4265352) for details.

Comment: This is useless. Let us admit. a fiasco in PHP exceptions. Even a fully php fiasko. I do not know why I'm still trying to learn php.